# Multiple map[string]interface and and mapping them to multiple json files GOLANG

Tags: json, go

How can i create and array of maps[string]interface to add multiple json files (not all json in one, but in different). I created a code, that add all json files in one. But in the future i need to compare field in map[string]interface. I think that need to create a loop. Here my program code:

```
var master map[string]interface{}

func main() {
    fileIndex := 3 // three json files. All named test1.json, test2.json and test3.json
    for i := 1; i <= fileIndex; i++ {
        fileName := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d%s", "test", i, ".json")
        // Open jsonFile
        jsonFile, err := os.Open(fileName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error:", err)
        }

        defer jsonFile.Close()

        byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

        json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &master)

        fmt.Println(master)

    }
}
```

And here my 3 json:
First:

```
 {
     "name":"Kate",
     "date":"2013-04-23T19:24:59.511Z",
     "data":"is nice"
 }
```

Second:

```
{
    "name":"Gleison",
    "date":"2012-04-23T19:25:00.511Z",
    "data":"is a good person"
}
```

Third:

```
{
    "name":"Rodrigo",
    "date":"2013-04-23T20:24:59.511Z",
    "data":"is kind"
}
```

It is necessary to divide them into different map[string]interface. Without creating struct.

Answer (score 0):

For an array, I think you are looking []map[string]interface{}. You can simply create this variable and append it if I understood your question correctly

Here is a modified example

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "os"
)

func main() {

    var master map[string]interface{}
    var allMaster []map[string]interface{}

    fileIndex := 3 // three json files. All named test1.json, test2.json and test3.json
    for i := 1; i <= fileIndex; i++ {
        fileName := fmt.Sprintf("%s%d%s", "test", i, ".json")
        // Open jsonFile
        jsonFile, err := os.Open(fileName)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Error:", err)
        }

        defer jsonFile.Close()

        byteValue, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(jsonFile)

        err = json.Unmarshal(byteValue, &master)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }

        allMaster = append(allMaster, master)
        fmt.Println(allMaster)

    }
}
```

Comment: Can i use it to add json files to different map[string]interface, because in the future i need to compare date's in different json files?

Comment: you mean the json keys can be different in future?

Comment: in the future, i need to aggregate date's by hours, days, months, years. So, i need to have opportunity to compare date's, i created a code that read only 2 json files and aggregated them, but now i need to do it for multiple json files.

Comment: I think you can give your program a read directory where all files are listed, it should be able to index it and read all

Comment: can you say how can i do this?

Comment: files, err := FilePathWalkDir(directory)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    for _, file := range files {
        fmt.Println(file)
    }

Comment: This is add index to the all files?

Comment: you can the list of files in a directory, hence you can simply iterate over it

Comment: Okay, thank you! if i will have some questions, can i ask you?

Comment: hey, after reading all files, i need to unmarshall then to map, and i have index, how can i use them to compare date's? I got smth like this:
    0
 map[data:is nice date:2013-04-23T19:24:59.511Z name:Kate]
1
map[*json1*]
2
map[json2]

Comment: now how can i compare fields inside map[string]interface in different json files? need to compare index, and trying to find equal date's interval.

Comment: you can parse dates and compare them.

Comment: parse date? like for index, file := range files["date"] {}
But how i can get access to the field using index?

Comment: i guess i have a problem to have an access to the field in map again, but now i have index, how can i use it?

Comment: its an array. you can easily iterate and then use key to get your dates

Comment: i tried, and i got an error: map not supporting indexing

Comment: how can i create this iterate? because i really dont know